# i want to compare if useranme exist in database or not

Tags: java, android, database, sqliteopenhelper

i want to take data from database and compare it with some inputed text i.e want to checck if username is already presnt in database or not.

here is my code of DBHelper.

```
public Boolean checkusername(String name) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true,Login_Table, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME,KEY_STATUS }, KEY_USERNAME

                    + "=" + "'" + name + "'", null, null, null, null, null);



    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        return true;

    }

    return false;
```

}

code where comparison is done

```
public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener


{
 // Variable Declaration should be in onCreate()
 private Button mSubmit;
 private Button mCancel;

 private EditText mFname;
 private EditText mLname;
 private EditText mUsername;
 private EditText mPassword;
 private EditText mEmail;
 private Spinner mGender;
 private String Gen;
 boolean check;
```

> private DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this);

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.register);

  //Assignment of UI fields to the variables
  mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
  mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

  mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
  mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

  mFname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.efname);
  mLname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.elname);

  mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reuname);
  mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repass);
  mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eemail);


  mGender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

  // Spinner method to read the on selected value
  ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] { 
            new State("Male"), 
            new State("Female")});
  mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
  mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 



 }

 public static boolean isvalidEmail(String email) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
        CharSequence inputStr = email;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }




 public void onClick(View v) 
 {

  switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.cancel:
   Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Home.class);
   startActivity(i);
   //finish();
   break;

  case R.id.submit:


   String fname = mFname.getText().toString();
   String lname = mLname.getText().toString();

   String uname = mUsername.getText().toString();
   String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();
   String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
   String status="s";


   boolean invalid = false;
  boolean checkEmail=isvalidEmail(email);



   if(fname.equals(""))
   {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
       if(fname.matches("[0-9]+" ))
               {
           invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter valid name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               }
   else
       if (fname.matches(".*\\s+.*"))
       {
           invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spaces are not allowed in Firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   else

   if(lname.equals(""))
   {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Lastname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
       if (fname.matches(".*\\s+.*"))
       {
           invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spaces are not allowed in Lastname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   else

    if(uname.equals(""))
    {
     invalid = true;
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
           if (uname.matches(".*\\s+.*"))
           {
               invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spaces are not allowed in Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
    else


      if(pass.equals(""))
     {
      invalid = true;
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
      else
       if (pass.matches(".*\\s+.*"))
       {
           invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spaces are not allowed in Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     else 
      if(email.equals(""))
   {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
      else if(checkEmail==false)
      {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      else
```

> DB.open();
>
> ```
>   if (DB.checkusername(uname)) {
>
>       invalid = true;
>       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "username alredy in use enter another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>   }
> ```

```
     else
      if(invalid == false)
      {
       addEntry(fname, lname, Gen, uname, pass, email);
       login( uname, pass, status);
       Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration.this, Login.class);
       startActivity(i_register);
       //finish();
      }

      break;
      }


    }





 public void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();
  DB.close();
 }

private void login(String username,String password,String status)
{

      SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put("username", username); 
      values.put("password", password);
      values.put("status", status);
      try
      {
       db.insert(DBHelper.Login_Table, null, values);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
}


 private void addEntry(String fname, String lname, String Gen, String uname, String pass, String email) 
 {

  SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("firstname", fname);
  values.put("lastname", lname);
  values.put("gender", Gen);
  values.put("username", uname);
  values.put("password", pass);
  values.put("email", email);


  try
  {
   db.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your details submitted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }



}
```

here is error logcat

```
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at com.google.data.DBHelper.checkusername(DBHelper.java:164)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at com.google.data.Registration.onClick(Registration.java:209)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-07 02:02:48.623: E/AndroidRuntime(8297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why would you ever do .equals(true)?

Comment: because checkusername returns true  if  username already present in database.

Comment: if (DB.checkusername(uname)) works the same and isn't ugly

Comment: yup u r write i hv chngd it..:)

Comment: sorry i didnt understand wat r u syng?? plzz xpln me

Answer (score 0):

It seems without `open` the database you are performing `query`. you need to first open database before performing any operations.

Example:  `db.open()`

Comment: That is same error NullPointerException. It happens you call any operation on reference which points to Null;

Comment: i have uploaded whole activity can u please tell where is prblm??